# Does a dominant morphism induce a surjection in (first) homology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $X$, $Y$ be complex normal quasi-projective varieties and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a dominant morphism. I would like to ask if the following statements are true:

1. $f_{*}\colon H_{1}(X; \mathbb{Q})\to H_{1}(Y; \mathbb{Q})$ is
   surjective.
2. Assume further that the fibers of $f$ are connected. Then $f_{*}\colon
   H_{1}(X; \mathbb{Z})\to H_{1}(Y; \mathbb{Z})$ is surjective.

For example, if $X$, $Y$ are projective curves then these assertions hold by the Hurwitz formula. I think I can prove assertion 1. using the answers to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/172521) question (after compactifying and resolving singularities), but I am not sure, and anyway I would like to ask if there is any simpler way to show this.

The additional assumption in (2) is clearly necessary, since we can kill torsion by a finite cover.

**EDIT**: as @KReiser points out [below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310280/does-a-dominant-morphism-induce-a-surjection-in-first-homology?noredirect=1#comment6811944_3310280), it suffices to show it for an open inclusion $X\subset Y$. Indeed, since $f$ is generically smooth, there is a proper closed subset $D\subsetneq Y$ such that $f|_{X\setminus f^{-1}(D)}\colon X\setminus f^{-1}(D) \to Y\setminus D$ is a fiber bundle (in the smooth category), so it satisfies (1) and (2) by the Serre exact sequence. Now if the map $\iota_{*}\colon H_{1}(Y\setminus D;\mathbb{Z})\to H_{1}(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ induced by the inclusion is surjective, then (1) and (2) follow by the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

I think that if $\mathrm{codim}\,_{Y} D\geq 2$ then $\iota_{*}$ is a isomorphism by the Nagata purity theorem. In any case, the surjectivity of $\iota_{*}$ should somehow follow from the fact that $D$ is of *real* codimension at least two. However, I find it difficult to fill in the details.

Comment: How do you get around the issue of an inclusion of an open set with no $H_1$ into a variety with $H_1$? This would seem to be the essential difficulty - in the case where $X,Y$ are both projective, dominant implies surjective, so nothing like this can happen. (On the other hand, I don't have an obvious example that this can happen immediately available either.)